# What HTTP framework to use for simple but scalable app?

Tags: python, http, frameworks, scalability

What HTTP framework should I use for a simple application with implied scalability, priferable Pythonic? I would like to be able to smoothly add new features to my app when it has already been deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Web.py](http://www.webpy.org.)

It might look too simple, but it's a joy to use.

It can be deployed on google appengine. Should scale pretty well. Can be used with any [WSGI](http://www.wsgi.org.) server.

Comment: Thanks, it looks nice, I'm diving into it right now. Do you know how to call run()? The tutorial says it's web.run. But thre seems to be no run() in web module.

Comment: Call the run() method of your application object (it's app.run() usually).

Comment: I think I haven't built an app yet. In the tutorial http://webpy.org/tutorial2.en there is this: import web; urls=('/', 'index', '', 'index'); class index: def GET(self): print "Hello World!"; web.run(urls, globals()); How do I fix so that it starts?

Comment: I found the answer: in web.py 3 you should do app = web.application(urls,globals()); app.run()

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan of [Pylons](http://pylonshq.com). It behaves just like a framework should; not excessive on the magic and contains many good components that you can pick-and-choose that help you hit the ground running. It's small and easy to deploy, and requires minimal boilerplate or other syntactic cruft. Scalability seems pretty good -- I've not run into any issues, and major parts of Reddit utilize libraries from Pylons.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably one of the most scalable solutions: G-WAN + Python:

http://forum.gwan.com/index.php?p=/discussion/comment/4126/#Comment_4126

Their scalability tests (like the results) are peerless.